# How do i use C# to to return element values using XPath?

Tags: c#, xpath

I have a snippet of an xml file that looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="wa_xml2html.xsl"?>
<computeraudit>
    <title>Computer Audit :: 11/13/2012 10:43:22 AM</title>
    <category title="Loaded Modules">
        <subcategory title="">
            <recordset title="">
                <fieldname>Name</fieldname>
                <fieldname>Version</fieldname>
                <fieldname>Modified</fieldname>
                <fieldname>Manufacturer</fieldname>
                <datarow>
                    <fieldvalue>XmlLite.dll</fieldvalue>
                    <fieldvalue>1.3.1000.0</fieldvalue>
                    <fieldvalue>7/13/2009 8:16:21 PM</fieldvalue>
                    <fieldvalue>Microsoft Corporation</fieldvalue>
                </datarow>              
                <datarow>
                    <fieldvalue>zip.dll</fieldvalue>
                    <fieldvalue>6.0.250.6</fieldvalue>
                    <fieldvalue>5/25/2011 8:30:12 AM</fieldvalue>
                    <fieldvalue>Sun Microsystems, Inc.</fieldvalue>
                </datarow>                      
            </recordset>
        </subcategory>
    </category>         
</computeraudit>
```

I'm trying to parse it with C# XPath and get each of the fieldvalue element values.

The c# code looks like this:

```
        XPathNavigator nav;
        XPathDocument docNav;
        XPathNodeIterator NodeIter;
        String strExpression;
        docNav = new XPathDocument(@"C:\TEMP\WinAudit\test.xml");

        nav = docNav.CreateNavigator();

        strExpression = "/computeraudit/category[@title=\"Loaded Modules\"]/subcategory/recordset/datarow";

        NodeIter = nav.Select(strExpression);

        while (NodeIter.MoveNext())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(NodeIter.Current.Value);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

It returns one line for each datarow node with all of the fieldvalue element values concatenated together.

How do I return each of the distinct values for each fieldvalue element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your XPath expression to:

```
"/computeraudit/category[@title=\"Loaded Modules\"]/subcategory/recordset/datarow/fieldvalue"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is only selecting the datarow elements.

Try `strExpression = "/computeraudit/category[@title=\"Loaded Modules\"]/subcategory/recordset/datarow/fieldvalue";`